# Yellow triangles on the Nuget items? Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "NHibernate"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

(Visual Studio 2019, .Net framework, C# projects)

I checkout an old C# (.Net framework 4) solution (which was developed by someones I don't know) with a lot of projects from a repository. However, there are a lot of errors which are caused by Nuget packages not loaded correctly (there are small yellow triangles on these packages).

The following xml code is copied from the `.csproj` files. All these `Reference`s with `HintPath` have the error. It seems the original developers save the dll files to a separated folder `..\..\Lib\`.

However, the folder **doesn't exist**. How to resolve the issue?

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Castle.Core">
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\NHibernate\Fluent\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Castle.DynamicProxy2">
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\NHibernate\Fluent\Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FluentNHibernate">
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\NHibernate\Fluent\FluentNHibernate.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="log4net">
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\Log4net\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NHibernate">
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\NHibernate\Fluent\NHibernate.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle">
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\NHibernate\Fluent\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The output window shows the following message,

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "NHibernate". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
>
> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Comment: I tried to remove and re-add the nuget package. Not working.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, I tried the steps in your answer but it didn't resolve the issue. I tried on a project has only NHibernate issue.

Comment: I cannot find `packages.config` in the old repo. (It's under the user directory `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and shouldn't exist in the repo?)

Comment: [Nuget.config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)(under `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`) file stores your local vs nuget management information. And you can delete it, when you restart VS, it will be generared by VS system. [packages.config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#examples) file records all the nuget packages in your current project. With this file, you can run restore or reinstall in the case of missing packages in the project to be able to restart Find these packages. So these two files are quite different.

Comment: Without this file, your project cannot find the missing nuget packages. So l think your old project has some strange,special modifications.However, in fact, such project should have packages.config file. I suggest you could right-click your project and then add a file called `packages.config` and then add these: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <packages> <package id="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" version="3.3.3.4000" targetFramework="target framework version of your project like `net472`" /> <package id="FluentNHibernate" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />.......</packages>`.

Comment: Then with this, you can run reinstall command as l said before to find the missing packages.

Answer (score 2):

I am quite confident that the solution does not use NuGet. The original developer almost certainly checked in binaries into source control, in that `lib` directory.

NuGet does add `<HintPath>` elements into the project when the project uses `packages.config`, which was the only option available before Visual Studio 2017. However, the default directory is `$(relative path to solution directory)\packages`, not `$(..)\lib`, although this can be changed with a `nuget.config` file.

But, NuGet has a specific folder structure within the `packages` folder, which will always be `$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion)`. Since the subfolders under `lib` just say `NHibernate` and `log4net` without a package version, it's not possible for this to have originally come from NuGet. edit: in addition, assemblies within a package are always in a `lib\` folder, so if the assembly came from NuGet, the hint path should be `..\packages\log4net.1.2.3\lib\<tfm>\log4net.dll`. Technically the `<tfm>` part is optional for packages that only want to support `packages.config`, but the vast majority of packages do use it. I'd be shocked if a package as popular as log4net or nhibernate didn't use the `<tfm>` folders. So, there's basically no chance that this was ever installed through NuGet.

If you wish to start using NuGet, you can remove the references to those assemblies (either in VS, or hand edit the csproj), and then use NuGet's Package Manager UI to install the packages. It'll add the relevant references back, this time with a hint path to a NuGet folder that will exist.

Comment: I guess the company didn't allow developers to use the external library a few years ago. There are many projects (30+) projects. I guess it may be easy to reconstruct the `Lib\` folder? Is it possible to download these DLLs from nugets?

Answer (score 0):

That's ok to save libs to a separate folder e.g. out of repository.
It seems your app can't to get this dll-s.
First check if dll-s exist in these folders.
The second - try to repair/re-download libs from nuget.
If it wont work, provide more info about warnings

Comment: The folder doesn't exist.

Comment: soo this folder really doesn't exist?
Try to check slashes, maybe it locating in child or parent of dir

Comment: I often facing with problem, when lib from nuget saves incorrectly.
You should to try repair them. 
Try to update lib, then return version back, check if dll of this lib downloading successfully.
Try to use visual studio features like restore nugets, reinstall...

Comment: How to "restore nugets" in visual studo? I thought it's done automatically?

Comment: Perry has wrote that I meant)
Right click on solution, restore nugets,
Or update-Package -reinstall in package manager console

Answer (score 0):

> However, the folder doesn't exist. How to resolve the issue?

I think you are moving your project to a new environment. In the previous environment, you changed the repositoryPath of the `nuget.config`(restore the mechanism for nuget in the current VS environment) file to a folder called **Lib**. You can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section).

**So** it displays as

```
<HintPath>..\..\Lib\NHibernate\Fluent\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll</HintPath>
```

**However**, in your new environment, there are no changes to your current vs nuget configuration information using the default address, it like

```
<HintPath>..\..\packages\NHibernate\Fluent\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll</HintPath>
```

**And** the conflict is between the current default nuget mechanism and the previous nuget mechanism.

**Suggestion**

**As a suggestion**, please try my steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)** close VS Instance, delete the`Nuget.Config` under `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`

**2)** reopen your project-->Right-clcik on the Solution and choose `Restore Nuget Packages`

[image]

**3)** `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manage Console` and then type

`update-Package -reinstall`

**In addition**, if these do not work, you should manually remove these packages.

Before it, please delete the `Nuget.Config` first.

**1)** make a list to record the names of these nuget packages and then delete `<Reference>`
 tag of these nuget packages in the `xxxx.csproj`, `packages.config` file.

**2)** [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and then install these packages on `Manage NuGet Packages`(Right-click on the project-->`Manage NuGet Packages`).

Hope it helps.

Comment: If the user has credentials saved in their profile nuget.config, deleting it is a bit irresponsible as they'll probably need to regenerate access tokens and re-save them. I really don't understand what kind of problem deleting the nuget.config is supposed to solve. Particularly, as my answer points out, those HintPaths point to places that NuGet couldn't possible have created in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I resolved that issue doing this:

- Opening **Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings**

Verifying that both checkboxes on Package Restore are checked and clicking **Clear All NuGet Cache(s)** button

[image]